# C# row direction

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I am working on GUI. I have a game board which is displayed by using a TableLayoutPanel. It has 6 columns and 7 rows. The square numbers are in the correct sequence and they should go right to left on some rows.
For example;

---

- 23-22-21-20-19-18
- 12-13-14-15-16-17
- 11-10-9-8-7-6
- Start-1-2-3-4-5

But in my code square numbers are always left to right. Could you please help?

```
    private void SetupGameBoard() {
    int counter = 0;

    for (int row = NUM_OF_ROWS-1; row > -1; row--) {
        for (int column = 0; column < NUM_OF_COLUMNS; column++) {
            SquareControl squareControl = new SquareControl
                (hareAndTortoiseGame.Board.Squares[counter], hareAndTortoiseGame.Players);
            if ((row == 6 && column == 0) || (row == 0 && column == 5)){
                squareControl.BackColor = Color.BurlyWood;
            }
            GameTableLayout.Controls.Add(squareControl, column, row);
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are only iterating in one direction and that is from left to right. Your first for loop needs to alternate between iterating columns up and down.

You want a game board that sort of zig-zags down the rows. Your logic for iterating down the rows is fine, you start at the highest row and move down. Now you just need to tackle the columns. You state that the values in the columns are always left to right when they come out right now. That is, I assume they look like:

- 23-22-21-20-19-18
- 17-16-15-14-13-12
- 11-10-9-8-7-6-5
- 4-3-2-1-start

This is because your column value always goes from 0->max, but you havent covered max->0.

some peusdo code:

```
for number of rows
  if row % 2 == 0 //if we are on an even row
    iterate up
  else
    iterate down
```

some untested actual code:

```
private void SetupGameBoard() {
        int counter = 0;

        for (int row = NUM_OF_ROWS-1; row > -1; row--) {
            if(row % 2 == 0){
               for (int column = NUM_OF_COLUMNS; column > -1; column--) {
                SquareControl squareControl = new SquareControl
                    (hareAndTortoiseGame.Board.Squares[counter], hareAndTortoiseGame.Players);
                if ((row == 6 && column == 0) || (row == 0 && column == 5)){
                    squareControl.BackColor = Color.BurlyWood;
                }
                GameTableLayout.Controls.Add(squareControl, column, row);
                counter++;
               }
            }
            else{
               for (int column = 0; column < NUM_OF_COLUMNS; column++) {
                SquareControl squareControl = new SquareControl
                    (hareAndTortoiseGame.Board.Squares[counter], hareAndTortoiseGame.Players);
                if ((row == 6 && column == 0) || (row == 0 && column == 5)){
                    squareControl.BackColor = Color.BurlyWood;
                }
                GameTableLayout.Controls.Add(squareControl, column, row);
                counter++;
               }
            }
        }
```

you can obviously break some of that out into other methods because there is a lot of repeating stuff. The idea is that you complete the zig-zagging based on if you are on an odd row or an even row.

Comment: The code snippet you showed is iterating up. That is, the columns are going left to right. You need another for loop that goes right to left to add controls to the board.

Comment: I tried everything which I can do, it doesn't work. could you please explain it more?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to do some math.  Here is the math to loop over all the cells (by cell number) and get the row and column.  I leave the rest to you.  NOTE: I did not test... might be typos or syntax errors.

```
const int maxCols = 6;
const int maxRows = 4;

int numberCells = maxCols * maxRows;  // zero based in main array.

for (int cellNumber = 0; cellNumber < numberCells; cellNumber)
{
     int row;
     int col;

     row = maxRows - floor(cellNumber / maxRows);

     bool oddRow = (row % 2) == 1;

     col = oddRow ? (cellNumber % maxCols) + 1 : maxCols - (cellNumber % maxCols);

     // I believe the following is what you want to do in your proc.
     SquareControl squareControl = new SquareControl(hareAndTortoiseGame.Board.Squares[cellNumber], hareAndTortoiseGame.Players);
     if ((row == 6 && col == 0) || (row == 0 && col == 5))
     // if ((cellNumber == 0) || (cellNumber == (numberCells-1)))
     {
        squareControl.BackColor = Color.BurlyWood;
     }
     GameTableLayout.Controls.Add(squareControl, col, row);

}
```